# DrvFs location of %UserProfile%

Tags: bash, path, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

From within the Windows Subsystem for Linux, how can I get the DrvFs path that points to what would be `%UserProfile%` inside the Windows personality?  I've seen [Access Windows Environment Variables from within Bash in WSL](http://blog.twimager.com/2017/05/access-windows-environment-variables.html). It seems rather involved for getting *one* environment variable, and requires hard-coding something from within `%UserProfile%` anyway (`$LXSS_ROOT`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
win_userprofile="$(cmd.exe /c "<nul set /p=%UserProfile%" 2>/dev/null)"

win_userprofile_drive="${win_userprofile%%:*}:"
userprofile_mount="$(findmnt --noheadings --first-only --output TARGET "$win_userprofile_drive")"

win_userprofile_dir="${win_userprofile#*:}"

userprofile="${userprofile_mount}${win_userprofile_dir//\\//}"
```

Thanks to [Craig Loewen](https://twitter.com/craigaloewen/status/883361886820999169) at Microsoft for getting me started.

Comment: Is there a special reason for redirecting stderr? `2>/dev/null`?

Comment: I believe on older versions of WSL this would suppress the "Unable to translate current working directory" warning if the current working directory isn't in DrvFs. On my current version (10.0.16299.19) this doesn't happen anymore. If you're only running on newer WSL, you don't need it anymore and probably a good idea to remove rather than silence unexpected errors.

Comment: FYI: Now it is a lot easier to achieve this, see my question in https://superuser.com/questions/1271205/how-to-get-the-host-user-home-directory-in-wsl-bash

Comment: The new `/bin/wslpath` currently only appears to be on the "Insider Build" but should be a better solution than my answer once it is widely available.

Comment: I'm not on insider, and it's available for me, you need to do windows update :P

Comment: In that case it might be because I have the "legacy" WSL rather than newer distributions from the Windows Store.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately since Windows 10 build 17063 (included in Windows 10 1803) there is a more straightforward way of sharing environment variables between Windows and WSL (`WSLENV`).

To make `%USERPROFILE%` accessible in WSL you list the variable in the `WSLENV` variable. If you are not using `WSLENV` yet then just run this once in Windows:

```
setx WSLENV USERPROFILE/up
```

This will cause `%USERPROFILE%` from Windows to be accessible as `$USERPROFILE` in WSL shell with Windows path converted to the Unix format. If you do not want to convert the path, just omit the `p`:

```
setx WSLENV USERPROFILE/u
```

More details:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#share-environment-variables-between-windows-and-wsl
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/

---

I use the variable in my `cdw` function (cd to Windows path). I define it in `~/.bash_aliases` which is executed automatically in Ubuntu:

```
#!/bin/bash

cdw () {
        if test "$#" -eq 0 ; then
                cd "$USERPROFILE"
        elif test "$1" = - ; then
                cd "$1"
        else
                cd -- "$(wslpath "$@")"
        fi
}
```